# Scaling Akka.Net

Tags: c#, akka.net

We use the Akka.net Framework for highly scaling applications in the energy sector.

We use Akka.net for various tasks, mostly in the following form:

```
var system=ActorSystem.Create("actorSystem");
var props=Props.Create<UpdateActor>();
               .WithRouter(new SmallesMailboxPool(100));
var actorRef=system.ActorOf(props,"UpdateActor");
foreach(var timerow in timeRowList)
   actorRef.Tell(timerow)
```

Unfortunately the Akka.net framework scales very badly in many cases.
The CPU load is only 12%.
Obviously only one thread or a few threads are used.

How can you configure Akka.Net to use multiple threads for processing the actors?

Answer (score 3):

This is an educated guess, but if you're using `SmallestMailboxPool`, keep in mind that it works pretty badly with non-blocking I/O and terribly with stashing.

First thing is usually to check, if there are no blocking operations (like synchronous I/O, calling `AsyncMethod().Result` or `Thread.Sleep`), which will block current thread, effectively preventing it from being used by other actors.

Another issue is very specific to smallest mailbox router, and it's related to stashing and persistent actors.

#### Stashing

Stashing is one of the popular ways to work with multi-step operations. This pattern can be represented as bellow.

```cs
  public class MyActor : ActorBase, IWithUnboundedStash
  {
     public IStash Stash { get; set; }

     public Receive Active(State workUnit) => message =>
     {
        switch(message)
        {
           case DoWork: 
              // stash all messages not related to current work
              Stash.Stash(message); 
              return true;
           case WorkDone done:
              // when current unit of work is done, unstash pending messages
              Stash.UnstashAll();
              Become(Idle);
              return true;
        }
     };

     public bool Idle(object message)
     {
        switch(message)
        {
           case DoWork work: 
              StartWork(work.State);
              Become(Active(work.State)); //continue work in new behavior
              return true;
           default: 
              return false;
        }
     } 

     public bool Receive(object message) => Idle(message);
  }
```

This case is pretty common i.e. **persistent actors** use it during their recovery process. Problem is that, it's cleaning up the mailbox, which gives `SmallestMailbox` routers a false sense that this actor's mailbox is empty, while in practice it's just stashing all incoming message.

This is also a reason why **peristent actors should not be routed using `SmallestMailbox` routers**! Tbh. I cannot think of any scenario where putting persistent actors behind router of any kind is a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is create an an actor coordinator class, and inside create a list/dictionary of actors. then (for what i understand) they should be working in parallel after you tell the coordinator about new updates.

```
public class UpdateCoordinator : ReceiveActor
{
    //all your update referenced
    private readonly Dictionary<int, IActorRef> _updates;

    public UpdateCoordinator()
    {
        _updates = new Dictionary<int, IActorRef>();

        //create the update reference
        Receive<UpdateMessage>(updateMessage =>
        {
            //add to the list of actors
            CreateUpdateReferenceIfNotExists(updateMessage.Identifier);

            IActorRef childUpdateRef = _updates[updateMessage.Identifier];

            //start your update actor
            childUpdateRef.Tell(updateMessage);
        });
    }

    private void CreateUpdateReferenceIfNotExists(int identifier)
    {
        if (!_updates.ContainsKey(identifier))
        {
            IActorRef newChildUpdateRef = Context.ActorOf(Props.Create(()=> new UpdateActor(identifier)), $"Update_{identifier}");
            _updates.Add(identifier, newChildUpdateRef);
        }
    }
}
```